# Unable to use iostream in node.js c++ module

Tags: node.js, debugging

I am trying to contribute to node.js development.

I have picked up an issue in the tracker, but dont know how to investigate . And I could not add traces to the c++ module that has the issue.

Is there any place where I could find basic information about the way to debug node.js ( trace, log,  debugger) ?

The way I tried to add traces :

```
#include <iostream>
//(...)
std::cout << value;
```

But the trace does not show.
I have a Windows system and run node from git bash with command : winpty node.

Is there something I miss to be able to use iostream in my configuration?